# Using Tabularize plugin

Tags: vim, macvim

How can modify this…

```
pt1 = [0, 1, 0]
pt2 = [0.588, -0.809, 0]
pt3 = [-0.951, 0.309, 0]
pt4 = [0.951, 0.309, 0]
pt5 = [-0.588, -0.809, 0]
```

…to make it look like this…

```
pt1 = [     0,      1, 0]
pt2 = [ 0.588, -0.809, 0]
pt3 = [-0.951,  0.309, 0]
pt4 = [ 0.951,  0.309, 0]
pt5 = [-0.588, -0.809, 0]
```

…using the [Tabularize plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)? It's all about regular expressions and I could not find one that works in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I make it this

```
:Tabularize /[,[]/l1c0r0c1r0c1r0
```

The spacing after the commas isn't quite right when I try Peter's suggestion, so I modified it slightly.

Answer (score 3):

Not using the Tabularize plugin, but the Align plugin:

```
:'<,'>Align! Wp11000P00110 = [[] , , []]
```

Explanation:

- You have 5 patterns on which to get alignment (`=`, `[`, `,`, `,` and `]`).
- The first two must be padded with one space on the left (`p11000`)
- The commas must be padded with one space after them (`P00110`)
- `W` preserves indentation

Comment: Thanks Benoit, I hadn't used Align yet, and this is a great example to start.

Answer (score 2):

This works nicely:

```
:Tabularize /[,[]/r1r0r0r0
```